# Exporting Wordpress Users to Json

Tags: json, wordpress

I would like to export my users database to json every night with a cron or something. Question is if anyone knows how to export my users to a json file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet below demonstrates how to use $wpdb to select all users from your wordpress instance, encode them into json, and then write the resulting json string to a plaintext file.

Hope this gets you what your looking for :).

```
public function export_users_to_json() {

    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_users";
    $users = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );                
    $json = json_encode($users);
    file_put_contents('users_export.txt', $json);                     

    die();
}
```